# How to enable autocomplete / IntelliSence for sass in vue files in VS Code?

Tags: vue.js, sass, visual-studio-code, intellisense, emmet

I use lang="sass" in my .vue files in VS Code, but the autocomplete / IntelliSence is not working for css properties.

(I already have Vetur installed)

Does anyone have a working solution or know what settings to enable or change?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Vetur handles CSS/SCSS, but I use Prettier and I manage the intelisense settings in the "extensions" settings group. There is a section specific to css preloaders within Prettier.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but i am using vueter also and in the settings in vs code i found the sass to be formatted with sass-formatter. So i installed that plugin form vs code sidebar, i was then instructed to also install sass/sass/sass from the sass website. I accomplished this with brew. sass is now supporting auto completion in *.vue files